# Re-list a item from a nested list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to figure how to pick all the fruits like:

```
[['id', 'sub type', 'type'], ['1', 'apples', 'fruit'], ['15', 'orange', 'fruit'], ['3', 'corn', 'vegtable']]
```

How do I output:

```
['sub type','apple','orange','corn']
```

Comment: corn isn't a fruit :)

Comment: @roippi Yes! This throws an error: `TypeError: Corn is not a fruit`.

Comment: Anyone try 'tomato'...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple as a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = [['id', 'sub type', 'type'], ['1', 'apples', 'fruit'], ['15', 'orange', 'fruit'], ['3', 'corn', 'vegtable']]
>>> [x[1] for x in lst]
['sub type', 'apples', 'orange', 'corn']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

`operator.itemgetter(1)` can be [higher-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287207/why-should-i-use-operator-itemgetterx-instead-of-x/11287230#11287230)

(*'Trivial answer converted to comment'?! WTF!*) This is the one-line reality. Prefer itemgetter to lambda expressions, for performance. Show us more context in which this code occurs, if you can.