# Sorting a tuple from smallest to largest number

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sot the following 'tupled' list from smallest to largest:

**`tuple1`**:

```
[('Bread', 3.1), ('Cheese', 8.2), ('Milk', 6.1), ('Pasta', 4.5) ...
```

I like to sort the tuple by integers, in ascending order - I have attempted the following:

```
>>> sortedTuple = tuple1.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0],int(x[1]))
```

However, I receive the following output:

```
None
```

My expected output would be:

```
[('Bread', 3.1), ('Pasta', 4.5), ('Milk', 6.1), ('Cheese', 8.2)...
```

Comment: You can use `sortedTuple = sorted(tuple1, key=lambda x: x[1])`. The lambda only requires you to specify the index that you want to sort on.

Comment: Your tuple1 is a list btw tuples don't have a sort method.

Comment: You know `tuple1` is actually a list and the reason you got `None` is because `list.sort` sorts a list *in place* and returns `None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` built-in function.

```
from operator import itemgetter

In [268]: tuple1
Out[268]: [('Bread', 3.1), ('Cheese', 8.2), ('Milk', 6.1)]

In [270]: res = sorted(tuple1, key=itemgetter(1))

In [271]: res
Out[271]: [('Bread', 3.1), ('Milk', 6.1), ('Cheese', 8.2)]
```

`key=itemgetter(1)` means the same thing as `key=lambda x:x[1]` that is to say the second element of your tuples will be used as keys for sorting. But it's supposed to be faster.

If you want, here is a discussion about using `itemgetter(x)` instead of `[x]`: 
[Why should I use operator.itemgetter(x) instead of [x]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287207/why-should-i-use-operator-itemgetterx-instead-of-x)

Comment: @BenF97 You say that you want to sort the tuple by integers, in ascending order, but what output do you expect for inputs like : `[('Milk', 3.4),('Bread', 3.1), ('Cheese', 3.2)]` ?

Comment: I'd expect the output to be: `[('Bread', 3.1), ('Cheese', 3.2), ('Milk', 3.4)]`. Would that not apply for your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) like this:

```
>>> tuples_list = [('Bread', 3.1), ('Cheese', 8.2), ('Milk', 6.1), ('Pasta', 4.5)]
>>> sorted(tuples_list, key=lambda item: item[1])
[('Bread', 3.1), ('Pasta', 4.5), ('Milk', 6.1), ('Cheese', 8.2)]
```

`sorted()` takes a second argument, which is `key`, in this case, we use [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to sort our list based on the second item (`item[1]`) of each tuple. By default, the first item (`item[0]`) would be used.

Comment: The question says that he wishes to sort based on the integer value, so you should cast the lambda key to int.

Comment: @lucianopaz did you take a look at the OP's attempt and expected output?

Comment: Yes, you get the same expected output because all values in the example differed by more than one. If this were not the case, the outputs could have been diferent.

Comment: In any case, BenF97 wishes to sort based on the int value and not on the float value.

Answer (score 0):

simple, like this.
    considered,

```
a=[('Bread', 3.1), ('Cheese', 8.2), ('Milk', 6.1), ('Pasta', 4.5)]

sort_2_value = sorted(a,key=lambda x: (x[1]))
```

Output:

```
>>>
[('Bread', 3.1), ('Pasta', 4.5), ('Milk', 6.1), ('Cheese', 8.2)]
>>>
```