# How to use min() only with first column of 2-dimensional list

Tags: python, max, min

I have 2-dimensional list in which each entry has a timestamp (int) and a second value that can be an int, string or object.

I'm using the min() function to get the entry with the lowest timestamp:

```py
a = [[2, "start C"],
     [6, 2484],
     [15, "finish C"]]

print(min(a))
```

Output:

```
[2, 'start C']
```

When there are identical lowest timestamps min() will compare the second column of those items.

This works only as long as the second column has comparable values:

```py
a = [[2, "start C"],
     [2, "start B"],
     [15, "finish C"]]

print(min(a))
```

Output:

```
[2, 'start B']
```

If the second column contains different data types it throws an error:

```py
a = [[2, "start C"],
     [2, 2484],
     [15, "finish C"]]

print(min(a))
```

Output:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

How can I let ***only the first column*** be checked for the minimum? 
When there are identical timestamps it should simply return the first item encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min` accepts a `key` argument, which can be used to obtain the expected behaviour:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [[2, "start C"],
     [6, 2484],
     [15, "finish C"]]

min(a, key=itemgetter(0))
# [2, 'start C']
```

Which is equivalent to slicing the inner lists with a custom lambda function as in @blue_note's solution, but typically somewhat faster (though its mainly a habit from being more convenient when having to fetch multiple items as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11287216/9698684)):

```
min(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

---

By using `itemgetter`, only the first element in each inner list will be fetched for ordering purposes, and then the minimum will be computed among this subset

Comment: You should probably also mention that this is equivalent to the `lambda` counterpart, but typically significantly faster.

Comment: The timing difference is a bit higher than what the wording of the most accepted answer from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11287216/9698684) seemed to indicate. See my [benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58171096/5218354) for some numbers for both `sorted()` and `min()`. My understanding is that with the `lambda` version there is an extra function call implicit to the `[]` operator.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a comparison key

```
min(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

By default, python uses the first item for comparison, and in case of tie, the second one as tie-breaker (and so on), that's why you get the error.