# Add values of repeated items from list to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the list

`list1 = [['P', '2.1'], ['C', '4.1'], ['S', '4.2'], ['M', '5.3'], ['A', '4.1'], ['C', '3.8'], ['C', '3.9'], ['M', '5.2'], ['A', '4.3'], ['P', '2.3'], ['C', '4.2'], ['A', '4.4']]`

and i have to create a dictionary adding the values of repeated items.

so far I have this:

```
for line in carsList:
     model = line[0]
     carsDict.update({model:[]})
     if model in carsDict:
         carsDict[model].append(float(line[1]))
```

But when I print what i got is:
`{'P': [2.3], 'C': [4.2], 'S': [4.2], 'M': [5.2], 'A': [4.4]}`

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've interpreted your question as meaning you want to sum the values for each key. There's a couple of ways you can achieve this. Using a `defaultdict` is probably the simplest:

```
from collections import defaultdict

carsDict = defaultdict(float)

for l in list1:
    carsDict[l[0]] += float(l[1])

print({ k : v for k, v in carsDict.items() })
```

but you can also implement it as a dictionary comprehension:

```
carsDict = { k : sum(float(l[1]) for l in list1 if l[0] == k) for k in set(l[0] for l in list1) }
print(carsDict)
```

In both cases the output is

```
{'C': 16.0, 'M': 10.5, 'S': 4.2, 'P': 4.4, 'A': 12.799999999999999}
```

Comment: Yeah I also recommended `defaultdict(float)`. +1

Comment: I have asked OP to clarify the expected result as this entire answer could be wrong. Your answer is the best here though (it got my vote anyway) as it covers both bases.

Comment: Yeah I was unsure either. Thought it wouldn't hurt  to include both cases. Hopefully the OP can clarify :)

Answer (score 1):

You cleared the list every time by updating it to an empty list, so you only gets the last element.

```
for line in carsList:
     model = line[0]
     carsDict.update({model:[]}) # It clears out your list every time!
     if model in carsDict:
         carsDict[model].append(float(line[1]))
```

This is what you should do. You create a new list when it does not exist, and append to it if there is already a list.

```
for line in carsList:
    model = line[0]
    if not model in carsDict:
        carsDict[model]=[]
    carsDict[model].append(float(line[1]))
# {'A': [4.1, 4.3, 4.4], 'P': [2.1, 2.3], 'C': [4.1, 3.8, 3.9, 4.2], 'M': [5.3, 5.2], 'S': [4.2]}
```

If you want to calculate a sum of all the floats:

```
for line in carsList:
    model = line[0]
    if not model in carsDict:
        carsDict[model]=0
    carsDict[model]+=float(line[1])
# {'A': 12.8, 'P': 4.4, 'C': 16.0, 'M': 10.5, 'S': 4.2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
list1 = [['P', '2.1'], ['C', '4.1'], ['S', '4.2'], ['M', '5.3'], ['A', '4.1'], ['C', '3.8'], ['C', '3.9'], ['M', '5.2'], ['A', '4.3'], ['P', '2.3'], ['C', '4.2'], ['A', '4.4']]
result = {}

for k, v in list1:
    result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print(result)
```

---

or `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': ['4.1', '4.3', '4.4'],
 'C': ['4.1', '3.8', '3.9', '4.2'],
 'M': ['5.3', '5.2'],
 'P': ['2.1', '2.3'],
 'S': ['4.2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you run through the for loop, you reset the value of `model` to an empty list in your `carsDict`.

what you can do is:

```
for line in carsList:
    model = line[0]
    if model in carsDict:
        carsDict[model].append(float(line[1]))
    else:
        carsDict[model] = [float(line[1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group by the first item of each sublist:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [['P', '2.1'], ['C', '4.1'], ['S', '4.2'], ['M', '5.3'], ['A', '4.1'], ['C', '3.8'], ['C', '3.9'], ['M', '5.2'], ['A', '4.3'], ['P', '2.3'], ['C', '4.2'], ['A', '4.4']]

d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in list1:
    d[x].append(float(y))

print(dict(d))
# {'P': [2.1, 2.3], 'C': [4.1, 3.8, 3.9, 4.2], 'S': [4.2], 'M': [5.3, 5.2], 'A': [4.1, 4.3, 4.4]}

print({k: sum(map(float, v)) for k, v in d.items()})
# {'P': 4.4, 'C': 16.0, 'S': 4.2, 'M': 10.5, 'A': 12.799999999999999}
```

If we are only interested in summing the floats, using a `defaultdict(float)` is probably more faster than collecting all the floats in a list then applying `sum()`:

```
d = defaultdict(float)
for x, y in list1:
    d[x] += float(y)

print(dict(d))
# {'P': 4.4, 'C': 16.0, 'S': 4.2, 'M': 10.5, 'A': 12.799999999999999}
```

Also note that `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, so the `dict()` cast is not needed.

You could also sort by the first item then apply [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [['P', '2.1'], ['C', '4.1'], ['S', '4.2'], ['M', '5.3'], ['A', '4.1'], ['C', '3.8'], ['C', '3.9'], ['M', '5.2'], ['A', '4.3'], ['P', '2.3'], ['C', '4.2'], ['A', '4.4']]

print({k: [float(x[1]) for x in g] for k, g in groupby(sorted(list1), key=lambda x: x[0])})
# {'A': [4.1, 4.3, 4.4], 'C': [3.8, 3.9, 4.1, 4.2], 'M': [5.2, 5.3], 'P': [2.1, 2.3], 'S': [4.2]}

print({k: sum(float(x[1]) for x in g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(list1), key=lambda x: x[0])})
# {'A': 12.799999999999999, 'C': 16.0, 'M': 10.5, 'P': 4.4, 'S': 4.2}
```

Both solutions above show how to group and get the sum of the floats. The `groupby` solution is slower for grouping because it is using `O(NLogN)` sorting, whereas the `defaultdict` groups in `O(N)` time. We could also replace `key=lambda x: x[0]` with [`operator.itemgetter(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), which is slightly faster. More information about the speed difference between the two in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287207/why-should-i-use-operator-itemgetterx-instead-of-x).