# Getting selective data from nested python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is the format of nested list:

[['A', 0],['B', 0], ['V', 0], ['D', 0], ['E', 0], ['F', 0], ['G', 1], ['H', 1], ['I', 1], ['J', 3], ['K', 0]]

I have nested list in such format, I need to get top 3 nested lists which have max nested list integer value such as my result should be ['J', 3] , ['I', 1] , ['H', 1]
I have tried to use the nested loop where i can get the max integer but struck at getting the string of those max 3 integers

Can someone please help me out here

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

First order list by number in nested list. In lambda function I return the value that has to be used for ordenation (2nd element of nested list):

```
a = [['A', 0],['B', 0], ['V', 0], ['D', 0], ['E', 0], ['F', 0], ['G', 1], ['H', 1], ['I', 1], ['J', 3], ['K', 0]]

sorted_list = sorted(a, key=lambda n: n[1], reverse=True)
# [['J', 3], ['G', 1], ['H', 1], ['I', 1], ['A', 0], ['B', 0], ['V', 0], ['D', 0], ['E', 0], ['F', 0], ['K', 0]]
```

With this I could slice 3 first elements:

```
sorted_list = sorted_list[:3]
# [['J', 3], ['G', 1], ['H', 1]]
```

And finally get a list with only letter (string):

```
[l[0] for l in sorted_list]
# ['J', 'G', 'H']
```

All at once:

```
[n[0] for n in sorted(a, key=lambda n: n[1], reverse=True)[:3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@salpreh's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116089/getting-selective-data-from-nested-python-list/61116332#61116332) answer, you could also use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with `key` for a slight speed increase:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [['A', 0],['B', 0], ['V', 0], ['D', 0], ['E', 0], ['F', 0], ['G', 1], ['H', 1], ['I', 1], ['J', 3], ['K', 0]]

print(sorted(a, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True))
# [['V', 0], ['K', 0], ['J', 3], ['I', 1], ['H', 1], ['G', 1], ['F', 0], ['E', 0], ['D', 0], ['B', 0], ['A', 0]]
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287207/why-should-i-use-operator-itemgetterx-instead-of-x) offers some performance stats between the two.