# for loop in a list which contains dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I want to write a program which can print the team with the highest point and then the team with the second highest point and then the third team.

```
WorldCup=[
    {name:"Spain", points:9},
    {name:"Portugal",points:7},
    {name:"Iran",points:6}
]
```

I mean I want to put this list into a `forloop` and get this output:

```
Spain
Portugal
Iran
```

I'm not sure if it is possible in a list but it is okay if you can solve it in any possible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is already sorted from highest to lowest in terms of `points`. Lists are ordered, so you can rely on it to maintain order as you iterate it.

Therefore, you can print your names inside this `for` loop:

```
for team in WorldCup:
    print(team['name'])
```

However, I'm assuming this is ordering is just luck, and you want to handle any possible ordering of teams. If so, we can sort the teams in descending order by `points` using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and `reverse=True`.

For the sorting `key`, similar to other answers, we can use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). Using `itemgetter` instead of `lambda` is usually slightly faster, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287207/why-should-i-use-operator-itemgetterx-instead-of-x/58171096#58171096).

```
from operator import itemgetter

WorldCup = [
    {'name':"Spain", 'points':9},
    {'name':"Portugal",'points':7},
    {'name':"Iran",'points':6}
]

sorted_teams_desc = sorted(WorldCup, key=itemgetter('points'), reverse=True)

for team in sorted_teams_desc:
    print(team['name'])
```

**Output:**

```
Spain
Portugal
Iran
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
WorldCup=[
    {'name':"Spain", 'points':9},
    {'name':"Portugal",'points':7},
    {'name':"Iran",'points':6}
]

for team in sorted(WorldCup, key=lambda team: team['points'], reverse=True):
    print(team['name'])
```

Output:

```
Spain
Portugal
Iran
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort the data by `points` and print its `name` only

```
worldCup = [{'name':"Spain", 'points':9},{'name':"Portugal",'points':7},{'name':"Iran",'points':6}]
    
for item in sorted(worldCup, key=lambda x:x['points'], reverse=True):
  print(item['name'])
```